# Survival of relativistic debris

Tags: energy

We've seen it in a million stories--starships get destroyed in battle.  What happens afterwards, though?

How far can that debris go before it's eroded to harmless atoms?  There was a question about an object going 99.99% of lightspeed over on Worldbuilding which showed the object would be quickly vaporized in interplanetary space, but I'm thinking of stuff going at speeds measured in %c but not nipping at light's ankles.

(The other question isn't really misplaced as the question was about the impact effects, the questioner didn't expect there to be no impact!)

(And is there a better tag for this?  I sure can't find anything!)

Comment: I think you need to give us a more definite value range for the speed. Usually, "relativistic" applies to stuff with kinetic energy comparable to its rest mass. Eg, a body travelling at 0.4 *c* has KE ~= 0.091 of its rest mass. OTOH, a body travelling at a mere 2900 m/s ($10^{-5}c$) has KE equivalent to the explosive power of the same (stationary) mass of TNT.

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm thinking of quite a range of speeds.  And while you **could** measure your 2900 m/s as .001%c that's not what people would normally do.  I'm talking about speeds fast enough that would be a common measuring unit.

Comment: So speeds > 1% c?

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah, that would be a reasonable lower bound.